# How to get the sum of all values from a pusub subscription id in 30 minute intervals using GCP metrics explorer in MQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I want to use MQL to get the sum of values in a 30 minute interval from values.

I am currently  utilizing the `sent message count` metric as it seems to fit my needs.  I would like my output to  be grouped by the subscription id  and sum of all the values in the last 30 minutes .

I have tried a-lot of  different  combinations to achieve  my desired output with no luck.

currently I have this query :

```
fetch pubsub_subscription
| metric 'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/sent_message_count'
| group_by [resource.subscription_id], sum(value.size)
| align rate(30m)
| every 30m
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated . Thank you

Update:

So far I have gotten closer  to my desired output trying this query:

```
fetch pubsub_subscription
| metric 'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/sent_message_count'
| value [value.size: value.sent_message_count]
| group_by [resource.subscription_id], sum(value.size)
| every 30m
```

this query lets me see a count of messages ex. 18.77M
, 0.39M , etc . However when I add the `| align rate(1w)` it turns the value into `k/s` instead of `M` for ex. 1.29k/s, 0.01 k/s, etc

How do I convert these numbers to a total count of messages ?

Answer (score 0):

MQL has a [scale](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#scale-func) function that can be used to scale a value. In this case, adding a scale function after the align step can be used to scale this to have units as desired.The scale function will multiply a value with one unit by a scale factor that converts it to a value with a different unit.

For example, the expression scale(3 "min", "s") will convert the value 3 with units minutes (min) to the value 180 with units seconds (s). The same amount of time, expressed in different units. The units are given according to the  [UCUM](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#units-of-measure) Standards.